# My CSV data is getting truncated or concatenated

Tags: r

I can view data in my CSV file and it looks pretty normal.

[image]

However, when I try to import the data this way, all headers get concatenated together.

```
ann2012 <- read.csv2("C:\\Users\\annualsinglefile.csv", header = TRUE)
```

When I try to import the data this way, the headers appear fine, but the leading zeros in the first column are all dropping off...even though they are in the CSV file.

```
ann2012 <- read.table("C:\\Users\\annualsinglefile.csv", header = TRUE, 
sep = ",")
```

I tried a few different ways to add a leading zero (current length is 4 characters and it needs to be 5 characters).

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(ann2012$fips, 5, pad = "0")


str_pad(x, 8, pad = "0")


sprintf("%05s", 1)


library(stringi)
stri_pad_left(str=ann2012$fips, 5, pad="0")
```

It seems like that just changes the format of the data, but the underlying data does not change at all.  How can I update the first column to have leading zeros, or just import the data as-is, and preserve the leading zeros?  Thanks.

Comment: Use `readr::read_csv` for a bit more standardised behaviour, and make sure to specify the first column is text. For the `stringr` part, you didn't assign the result back to the original data, you just printed the transformed output.

Comment: I think you can use "colClasses" in `read.table` to get leading zeroes while reading the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
df <- read.csv("test.csv", header = T, colClasses = c("area_fips" = "character"))
```

which gives

```
> df
  area_fips own_code industry_code
1     01000        0             10
2     01000        0              1
3     01000        0            102

> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ area_fips     : chr  "01000" "01000" "01000"
 $ own_code      : int  0 0 0
 $ industry_code: int  10 1 102
```

**Sample data:**
`test.csv` contains

```
area_fips,own_code,industry_code
01000,0,10
01000,0,1
01000,0,102
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Prem!!

Comment: Glad that it helped!